# Regarding two inequalities

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{C}$. Let $\mathbb{T}$ denote the unit circle in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.
I want to know if the two conditions are equivalent:

1) $|b|<1$ and $|cz-a|^2<|bz-1|^2$ for every $z\in\mathbb{T}$.

2) $|a|^2-|b|^2+|c|^2+2|b-\bar{a}c|<1$.

I tried expanding condition 1) and got to the point $|a|^2-|b|^2+|c|^2+2 Re(bz-\bar{a}cz)<1$. Can you help me how to go beyond this?

Comment: $\lvert w\rvert = \max_{z \in \mathbb{T}} \operatorname{Re} (wz)$, so …

Answer (score 0):

Remeber that for all $w$ we have $Re(w)\leq |w|$ so we have $$Re(bz-\bar{a}cz)\leq |bz-\bar{a}cz| = |z||b-\bar{a}c| = |b-\bar{a}c|$$ So if second one is valid then first one is also valid. But not sure about vice versa.

Comment: Yes. This is quite obvious. But I am stuck at the converse.